# Creating a custom shape with border-radius

Tags: html, css

I want to create a shape like this:

[image]

It should fit into the screen and it should be cut on the left hand side.

How can i do this?

What i have now is this:

```css
    .shape {
      height: 92vw;
      width: 100vw;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      border-radius: 92vw 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: Why not make an SVG?

Comment: is it possible to style svg's with css?

Comment: Depends what you want to do, you can change colours etc inline

Comment: @olivier Yes, SVG can be styled with CSS as any other XML or HTML document.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy and feeela i was already able to do it. =)

Comment: @olivier Then be nice and post your solution as answer to your own question.

Comment: yep svg can be styled - but they need to be embedded inline in the DOM. check out http://www.grunticon.com/ to integrate SVG the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.shape {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape:before {
  content: '';
  height: 250vh;
  width: 250vw;
  background-color: #ecdbb0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -20vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with a SVG.

Thanks andy and feeela!

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#shape {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="shape" data-name="Form crop" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 928.08"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#ecdbb0;opacity:0.6;}</style></defs><title>shape</title><path class="cls-1" d="M2379.69,1551.29V623.21c-603.05,53.25-876.26,317.23-999.59,558.26l-0.41.8v369h1000Z" transform="translate(-1379.69 -623.21)"/></svg>
```

Comment: No problem :) Glad to be of help :)

Comment: In this example it doesn't work. Answer provided for LGSon is better I guess.

Comment: You can make it work with your SVG on all platforms, though with my suggested solution you get easier maintenance and full control of all part of the shape using standard CSS ... and no extra markup :)